# How do I quickly switch to/from the front panel speakers in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, switch, front-panel

I have speakers attached to my front panel sound output that I switch to frequently. Currently the process is to open Terminal, type "alsamixer", scroll over to "Front Panel", and press "M" to activate it. Although this doesn't seem like much, it's a hassle when switching between outputs frequently.

Are there any faster alternatives, such as a button that can be placed on the GNOME panel or a shortcut key that can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alsamixer` is meant to be used interactively. If you want to script volume changes then you should use `amixer` instead. Although, it seems strange that your audio card can't detect the jack status. You may want to examine the [`model`](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sound/alsa/ALSA-Configuration.txt) parameter of the sound driver in use, e.g. `snd-hda-intel` and see if setting it appropriately causes it to autosense.

Comment: Up-to-date model is here https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/sound/hd-audio/models.rst